# Resources for special functions

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, special-functions

What's a good book for learning about special functions as an undergraduate? I'd prefer information that would be useful to future work in string theory.

Comment: Well, the policy of this website advises against suggestions of books to study, so it may well be that your question is locked by the moderators. Until then, let me simply add that throughout your future education, the books by Arfken and later Nakahara on Math. Methods in Theoretical Physics will be almost indispensable.

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely recommend the text by James Seaborn *[Hypergeometric functions and their applications](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387975580)*.  This text is completely approachable and contains all the special functions required at the undergraduate level.  What makes this book different from more mathematical text is that the presentation is directly tied to physics, which gives it the advantage of being written using "the physics conventions".  The only drawback is that it is rather focused and so is limited in topics to special functions.

Comment: Check your link, I think maybe you forgot to copy and paste the right one.

Comment: @JamalS Thanks for the heads up.  Should work now.